# $\sum \frac{z^k}{k}$ does not converge uniformly on $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

> $\sum \frac{z^k}{k}$ does not converge uniformly on $|z|<1$

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/232889/668308) post, the answer says that as $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ does not converges, $\lim_{z\to 1^-,z\in\Bbb R}\sum\frac{z^k}{k}= \infty$. Why is this a valid proof?

If I have some series $\sum a_nz^n$ and I'm asked to show the series does not converge uniformly on $|z|<R$, then if I show $\sum a_nR^n$ does not converges, does that show the series $\sum a_nz^n$ does not converge uniformly?

Comment: I think it may be a little confusing that phrasing does(or does not) converge uniformly on $\;|z|<1\;$..." . What I think this means most of the times is that the series does (or does not) converge uniformly *on compact subsets* of $\;|z|<1\;$ ...and your series does converge in compact subsets of $\;|z|<1\;$ . That it doesn't converge on the convergence regio's boundary isn't surprising: it never does! Otherwise the convergence radius would be bigger...

Comment: On the boundary of the circle of convergence things can go in strange ways. in your particular case, things blow up at $1$.

Comment: this is a general topological result - if $f_n$ continuous on some complete metric space $M$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly on some subset $A$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\bar A$

Comment: @DonAntonio: On the boundary it can go either way -- for example, this series does converge (to $\log\frac12$) at $z=-1$.

Comment: @Troposphere Oh, I know that. I referred to the example given by the OP....and I should have added that in *all* of the convergence region's boundary. At particular points it can go either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving non-uniform convergence in this way follows from a simple fact.

> Suppose the partial sums are bounded, that is, there exists a sequence
> $(M_n)$ of positive real numbers such that $|S_n(z)| = \left|
>  \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(z)\right| \leqslant M_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
> and for all $z \in D$. If $S_n(z) \to S(z)$ uniformly for $z \in D$,
> then $S$ must be bounded on $D$.

To prove this, note that by uniform convergence there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|S_N(z) - S(z)| \leqslant 1$ for all $z \in D$. Hence $|S(z)| \leqslant |S_N(z) - S(z)| + |S_N(z)| \leqslant 1+ M_N$ for all $z \in D$.

Here we have $|S_n(z)| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z^k}{k} \right|\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{|z|^k}{k} \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\leqslant n = M_n$ for all $|z| < 1$. If the series converged uniformly the sum would have to be bounded for all $|z| < 1$ -- which it is clearly not.

Comment: You can also prove that the uniform convergence of a series with partial sums bounded this way implies that the partial sums are uniformly bounded for all $n$ and $z$. Again this fails to hold with your example.